# Elaborated difference between static and dynamic EMF

Tags: emf

I have seen two sources have contradicting takes on static and dynamic induced EMFS.

One source says that Static EMFs are produced by the circuit and magnetic field both being stationary. Dynamic EMFs meanwhile are produced when figuratively either the circuit cuts through the magnetic field or the magnetic field cuts through the circuit. Now I know what they actually say is change in flux but I'm just putting out a simple concept and in no way am claiming that it is near to what is actually happening. It is just a concept.

This idea is what I almost always get when I search in Google.

Another source says that both Static and Dynamic EMFs have either of the magnetic field or the circuit being moving. Which means there is no case where both the magnetic field and circuit are stationary. Static EMF is when the magnetic field cuts the circuit and Dynamic EMF is when the circuit cuts the magnetic field.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JN1Z5mgbORY

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbtp6bOn4WQ

These are my reference for the second ideas.

I just want a clear cut explanation on what they really are and a way to easily distinguish the two. I mean, I can totally elaborate what magnetic field cuts circuit and circuit cuts magnetic field are but my problem is distinguishing the two and how the applications really work. Sources do mention examples like transformers, self inductance and mutual inductance but because I am confused with the right idea, I don't really want to base it on the examples and leave it at there. I hope someone is able to explain and also relate those common examples.

Comment: What is your question (and note that I'm not going to follow youtube links to videos).

Comment: I want to know the difference between statically induced EMF and dynamic